# asp.net ms chart control multiple columns for x-axis

Tags: asp.net, mschart

How can I select a range of columns like Microsoft Excel for x-axis in MS-Chart control for asp.net?

How can I flip x-axis and y-axis like Microsoft Excel in MS-Chart control?

Thanks
Achuthan Sundar

Comment: Here is our table structure Sales_Person  Jan-2008  Feb-2008 mar-2008 apr-2008. Data Joe M   100  200  300  150. Mary Q 200 150 200 400. In essence monthly sales per sales person is in columns. We tried to add multiple series. We want Jan-2008 Feb-2008... in x-axis and y-axis will have sales. group by sales_person. But we could not find how to do this in MS-chart. Ms Excel this is very easy. If you can give some pointers I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should go here [ms chart samples and code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) go the the download tab and download both or the one you need, it helped me a lot to understand how the ms chart works, the samples are usefull.

Comment: I have checked the samples with adding series. But here is what I want. I have a table with sales data for every month. The columns I have is Sales_Per, Jan-2012, Feb-2012, March 2012, April-2012 and so on. I have Sales_Person name and Actual sales for each month. Now I want to plot Months in x-axis and sales in Y-axis for that month. How Can I do this in asp.net chart control? Microsoft Excel allows me to do this easily. But I need the same functionality in ASP.net using chart control.

Comment: In the ChartArea, there is an axes collection, set the x axis to the Month, set the y as numeric. The just add your series... I've worked mainly with it in forms but the essence must be the same.